# Required field and client side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have put  `[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]` in model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Display(Name = "Amount")]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

set these field true in webconfig

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

and

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

               <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount )</td>

                        <input onclick="return validate();" style=" margin:20px; width:120px; height:40px;" type="submit" value="ثبت فیش" />

    }
```

**button click not check validation ,** add this to controller for serverside validation

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                obj.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
                obj.OrderID = id;
                RingSportEntities objEntity = new RingSportEntities();
                objEntity.Payments.Add(obj);
                var p = (from o in objEntity.Orders where o.OrderId == id select o).First();
                p.Status = 2;
                objEntity.SaveChanges();
                return View();
            }
            else { return View(obj); }
```

now , it works serverside verfication , why client side now works ?

Comment: Did you include the jquery validate javascript file.

Comment: `jquery.validate.min.js` and `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js` included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

**View**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("YourPage", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmIndex" }))
        { 
<input type="submit" value="Save" style="float: left;" id="btnSave" title="btn" />
    }
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $("#btnSave").click(function () {

                var validation = $("#FrmIndex"); // My From Id
                if (!validation.valid()) {
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

You have to add this two script fro validation.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: or just add  `onclick="return validate();"` in input attribute instead if write js

Comment: @Moslem7026 sorry i just don't understand?

Comment: in mvc 4, including `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js' on page and `[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]` in model is enough and it doesn't need to write `onclick` function

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input onsubmit="return $(this).closest("form").valid();" style=" margin:20px; width:120px; height:40px;" type="submit" value="submit!" />
```

Comment: did you change onclick with onsubmit?

Comment: adding `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` to page solved problem